# Updating drupal commons issue

Tags: updating, security

Security Update for drupal

All other updates are being done smoothly thorugh drush

I have a multi site installation if drupal so i worried to remove the sites folder and update that the general way.

I get this error when updating through drush commons module:

The commons directory could not be found within the modules directory at /var/www/drupal/., perhaps the project  [error]
is enabled but has been deleted from disk.

Please help.

Comment: Was your site built by Drupal Commons from Acquia? Here is instructions on how to [upgrade Drupal Commons from Acquia](https://docs.acquia.com/commons/upgrade).

Comment: Yes when i am trying to upgrade commons 7.x-3.25 to 7.x-3.27 i am experiencing these errors

Comment: Can we do the upgrade using drush

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Durpal Commons, but I posted the upgrade path recommended by Acquia, so I would go that route.